# Accessing the Intranet MongoDB from external network

Tags: java, mongodb, tunneling

I am currently developing a code in which it needs to access to MongoDB which is in the company intranet. 
Actually connecting to MongoDB with GUI was easy, since we can simply use Robo 3T which offers a tunneling function. But the problem is that we need such function from the code(using Java driver) without connecting GUI.

Detail situation is like this.

- Computer A (External network)  : development environment which needs to access MongoDB (iP: 10.X.X.A)
- Computer B (Intra network ): head node & gateway (ip: 10.X.X.B, 192.168.0.B)
- Computer C (MongoDB server): we are only able to access from intranet(ip: 192.168.0.C)

So, it is possible to connect from Com-A to Com-B, and  from Com-B to Com-C, but not possible from Com-A to Com-C.
How can I implement to use mongoDB located in Com-C  from Com-A ? 
Is there any way to implement or trick?

If it is possible to implement that function, I would like to know if it is possible to implement in JAVA.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should have access to pass company firewall if exists.

Comment: @İlker Korkut  Yes passing the company firewall is already made but I would like to know a way to pass over one server to connect mongoDB server from external network.